# Google Map is not showing while map is console all the elements (on the Bootstrap modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Javascript Google Map is not showing while the map is console all the elements(On the bootstrap Modal)/.

I want to show google map on click button in the modal but the map is not showing.

But when I try to console the map. It works fine.

```
console.log(map);
```

Console result something like that:

```
Object { gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, center: {…}, zoom: 9, zoomControl: true, mapTypeId: "roadmap", j: undefined, mapTypes: {}, features: {}, … }
```

So what's the problem in my code.

Modal file is:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 420px;">
```

```
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ()
  { 

    load();

    });

  function load()
        {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.722956,76.76942),
                zoom: 9,
                zoomControl: true                  
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 3
            });
            poly.setMap(map);
            console.log(map);

            }

    </script>
```

Comment: If the map is in a Bootstrap modal you need to initialise it when the modal is displayed, not on page load. This is because the content is not visible up until that point

Answer (score 2):

Call load method after model load like

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  load();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of assumptions:
1. You have implemented all the necessary Bootstrap CSS/HTML/JS to make the modal work
2. Your modal has an ID
3. You have all the necessary Google Maps JS implemented to make the maps API work

If the above is true, you have to call the `load()` method when the modal is displayed and not when the page is loaded, because the content cannot be rendered at that moment yet.

So what you have to do is the following:

```js
function load() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.722956, 76.76942),
    zoom: 9,
    zoomControl: true
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });
  poly.setMap(map);
  console.log(map);
}

// #myModal is the ID of the modal div in your HTML
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  load();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run your code adding the jquery and google API without any difficulties. But there are some warnings.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  load();

});

function load() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.722956, 76.76942),
    zoom: 9,
    zoomControl: true
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });
  poly.setMap(map);
  console.log(map);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
<div id="map" style="height: 420px;">
```